# ArrayBlockingQueue - How to "interrupt" a thread that is wating on .take() method

Tags: java, concurrency

I use an `ArrayBlockingQueue` in my code. Clients will wait until an element becomes available:

```
myBlockingQueue.take();
```

How can I "shutdown" my service in case no elements are present in the queue and the `take()` is waiting indefinitely for an element to become available? This method throws an `InterruptedException`. My question is, how can I "evoke" an Interrupted Exception so that `take()` will quit? (I also tought about `notify()`, but it seems I doesn't help here..)

I know I could insert an special "EOF/QUIT" marker Element but is this really the only solution?

**UPDATE** (regarding the comment, that points to another question with two solutions):

one mentioned above using a "Poisoning Pill Object" and the second one is `Thread.interrupt()`:

The `myBlockingQueue.take()` is used **NOT** in a `Thread` (extending Thread) but rather implements `Runnable`. It seems a Runnable does not provide the `.interrupt()` method?

How could I interrupt the `Runnable`?

Comment: Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812342/how-to-interrupt-a-blockingqueue-which-is-blocking-on-take

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement the Runnable like this. (It assumes you have started the Runnable before you attempt to interrupt it)

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private Thread thisThread;
    public void run() {
       thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
       try {
          // do some work
       } catch(Throwable t) {
          t.printStackTrace(); // or log the error.
       } 
    }
    public void interrupt() {
       thisThread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward way is to keep a reference of the thread you use to run the runnable and interrupt it on shutdown.

Alternatively you can use thread pools to organize the threads for a service. Then the threadpool takes care of keeping track of the threads and managing them, including  interrupting them when shutting down.

Yet another (hacky and not recommended way) way is to enumerate all running threads in the JVM (using the ThreadGroup's method) and try to guess which thread runs your runnable (e.g. by analyzing the stack of each thread).

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

Either use, as described in the question an "Poisoning Object"

or

Interrupt the Thread eitehr with `this.interrupt()` or if it is a Runnable use `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();`

Comment: First part of the answer is correct, the second is nonsense. If you execute Thread.currentThread().interrupt(), you are interrupting the current thread, and if you can execute that you are clearly not blocked anywhere else.