# c#: how terminate a background thread in dispose() method?

Tags: multithreading

I have a program which runs a thread. The thread performs processing all the time and it uses some synchronized queue.

The class snapshot is as follows:

```
public class MyClass:IDisposable
{
    private Thread myThread = new Thread(threadFunc);
    private volatile bool runThread = true;

    public MyClass()
    {
        myThread.Start();
    }

    public Dispose()
    {
        runThread = false;
    }

    private void threadFunc()
    {
        try
        {
           while(runThread){
           queue.Take(); //This method blocks the thread if queue is empty. It uses Monitor class
   //do some processing
           }
        }
        catch(Exception e){...}
    }
    private void otherFunc()
    {
        queue.enqueue(...);//this method is executed by main thread and uses lock while adding element to the queue.
    }
}
```

When I call `Dispose()` method, the thread exists `threadFunc()` method, but after a sec I get an execption from this func "Unable to avaluate expression...", as if the tread was terminated while doing some work. Maybe it has just released from `queue.Take()` blocking and has no context to run. I know I'm missing something...

How can I solve such problem and terminate the thread from the Dispose method.

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Use the overload of `Take` that accepts a `CancellationToken`. You can get a reference to a token by using the `CancellationTokenSource` which also has the `Cancel` method that you can call from `Dispose` to unblock the `Take` method. You can read more cancellation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use the poison pill approach: [See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812342/how-to-interrupt-a-blockingqueue-which-is-blocking-on-take)