# How to shut down a waiting server?

Tags: java, sockets, shutdown, executorservice

I created a little (single thread) server and put the "work"-code in a `Runnable`. This runnable is then executed in a background-thread using Javas Executor Framework:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
exec.execute(runnable);
```

So now, I'm searching for a good way to shut this server down. I want to add the possibility to restart the Server without restarting the program, so terminating the whole process is not an option.

[What I have found](http://codeidol.com/java/java-concurrency/Task-Execution/The-Executor-Framework/#part-94) is something like this:

```
class LifecycleWebServer {
    private final ExecutorService exec = ...;

    public void start() throws IOException {
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(80);
        while (!exec.isShutdown()) {
            final Socket conn = socket.accept();
            // Do stuff with the connection...
        }
    }

    public void stop() { exec.shutdown(); }
}
```

The thing that bothers me is, that if the program has reached line 7 (`socket.accept()`), and I call the `stop()`-method, the Server will still wait until one last connection was made and then shutdown.

Is there any preferred way to deal with this?

Comment: I posted a similar question for socket code written in C/C++ and got a great answer. I suspect you need to use non-blocking sockets to achieve a similar effect.  Have you tried just closing the socket from the other thread and catching an exception thrown by socket.accept?  I'm actually not sure if that will work.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486335/wake-up-thread-blocked-on-accept-call

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983835/how-can-i-interrupt-a-serversocket-accept-method - seems like you need to close the socket.

Comment: [similar question][1]: - seems like you need to close the socket


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983835/how-can-i-interrupt-a-serversocket-accept-method

Comment: Could NIO be used to make the socket interruptible?  This certainly works for client sockets; I've never tried server sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seams that calling `close()` on the waiting `ServerSocket` is one way to do this. In that case, the `accept()`-method will throw a `SocketException`, which you'll need to catch.

Another, maybe clearer way is to use a "Poison Pill", which is explained in detail here: [How to interrupt a BlockingQueue which is blocking on take()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812342/how-to-interrupt-a-blockingqueue-which-is-blocking-on-take)