# Is an "atomic" interrupt check possible in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, interrupt

If using following "idiom" with interruption in Java, for example [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145787/how-to-safely-interrupt-a-thread-with-critial-atomic-logic/14145858#14145858).

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    try {
        Object value = queue.take();
        handle(value);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

Where [take](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take%28%29) is a blocking operation, can an interrupt not be ignored for the time being if an interrupt "arrives" between the check of `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` and the call `queue.take()`? Is this not a "check-than-act" operation? If so, can it somehow be guaranteed that the loop is left in any case if the thread is interrupted?

It is possible to use  [poll with a timeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#poll%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) so that the loop is left after the timeout, **but is it possible to check the interrupted status and act on it atomically?**

Comment: How could an interrupt ever be missed by the above code? You realize that queue.take() will throw immediately if the thread is interrupted before the call to take(), right?

Comment: @JBNizet: I have checked the code, and you are right, methods throwing `InterruptedException` check for the interupted status first and throw. If you add an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3):

I would swap the try/catch and while loop:

```
try {
  while (true) {
    Object value = queue.take();
    handle(value);
  }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

The `take()` operation will throw an `InterruptedException` immediately if the thread is interrupted, and at the same time break out of the while loop.

Comment: In the interrupt comes during handling, the exception may not be thrown. So - for sake of to be sure, I usually use while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())

Comment: @GabrielVince Please explain the circumstances under "the exception may not be thrown".

Comment: in case the "handle(..)" method is doing some computations, not necessarily waiting for I/O and the thread is interrupted, The exception is not thrown. I'd check it in the loop. I wouldn't assume the blocking I/O will throw an exception when the thread is entering with already interrupted state (though the comment from JB.Nizet states otherwise and I may be wrong here).

Comment: @GabrielVince The `handle()` function appears to be defined in the same class that you are editing.  It will throw an `InterrutpedException` if you change it to check the flag and throw the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Only a call could clear then interrupted flag so nothing could happend between isInterrupted and queue.take().

Answer (score 0):

> but is it possible to check the interrupted status and act on it
>   atomically

Well - I don't know what you mean "atomically" here. May we assume you want something like onInterrupt(...)?

Interrupts are meant to "interrupt" the thread, so all default I/O operations throw an InterruptedException you can catch or check. It give the threads opportunity to stop gracefully closing / releasing any locked resources.

As event handling you may want to implement a 
[Cancellable task](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/j2se/1.5.0/jcp/beta1/apidiffs/java/util/concurrent/Cancellable.html), where you could handle your own cancel events (well, not the default JRE interrupts).