# Java VM not shutting down due to BlockingQueue.take()

Tags: java, concurrency, blockingqueue

My app starts a daemon thread which uses a blockingQueue. When it is killed using kill -3, the app doesnt stop cleanly and the resulting stack shows that it is still waiting on `BlockingQueue.take()`.

Any suggestions to help with a clean shutdown would be deeply appreciated

Comment: Kill java.exe from task manager.

Comment: What does the `Runnable` in this daemon thread look like?

Comment: You can interrupt the queue on shutdown

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812342/how-to-interrupt-a-blockingqueue-which-is-blocking-on-take

Comment: When you say "daemon thread", did you call `Thread.setDaemon(true)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say...

```
...When it is killed using kill -3, the app doesnt stop cleanly and the...
```

Usually a Java app does not terminate by using Kill -3.

Kill SIGQUIT (-3) is used to take a Java thread dump.

Try using kill -9 or -15

If some special signal handling hook is enabled, this behaviour could change.

EDIT:

Also, a controlled, clean Java app shutdown is originated within the app.
Have a look at [How to gracefully handle the SIGKILL signal in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541597/how-to-gracefully-handle-the-sigkill-signal-in-java)

Comment: Thank you for the lucid explanation. Kill -2 works for me and shuts down the app cleanly (calling all runtime hooks)

Answer (score 0):

`BlockingQueue#take` respond to interruption, so you simply need to make sure that you interrupt the thread that executes the `take` method and handle the thrown `InterruptedException` adequately (i.e. by exiting the method).

If the thread in question is managed by a thread pool, you can `shutdownNow` the pool, which will interrupt the thread too.