# Java thread not responding to volatile boolean flag

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to Java concurrency, and I met a very strange problem:
I read from a large file and used several worker threads to work on the input (some complicated string matching tasks). I used a LinkedBlockingQueue to transmit the data to the worker threads, and a volatile boolean flag in the worker class to respond to the signal when the end-of-file is reached.

However, I cannot get the worker thread to stop properly. The CPU usage by this program is almost zero in the end, but the program won't terminate normally.

The simplified code is below. I have removed the real code and replaced them with a simple word counter. But the effect is the same. The worker thread won't terminate after the whole file is processed, and the boolean flag is set to true in the main thread.

The class with `main`

```
public class MultiThreadTestEntry
{
    private static String inputFileLocation = "someFile";
    private static int numbOfThread = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        Worker[] workers = new Worker[numbOfThread];
        Scanner input = GetIO.getTextInput(inputFileLocation);
        String temp = null;
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numbOfThread);
        LinkedBlockingQueue<String> dataQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>(1024);

        for(i = 0 ; i < numbOfThread ; i ++)
        {
            workers[i] = new Worker(dataQueue);
            workers[i].setIsDone(false);
            es.execute(workers[i]);
        }

        try
        {
            while(input.hasNext())
            {
                temp = input.nextLine().trim();
                dataQueue.put(temp);
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        input.close();

        for(i = 0 ; i < numbOfThread ; i ++)
        {
            workers[i].setIsDone(true);
        }

        es.shutdown();

        try 
        {
            es.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

The `worker` class

```
public class Worker implements Runnable
{
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<String> dataQueue = null;
    private volatile boolean isDone = false;

    public Worker(LinkedBlockingQueue<String> dataQueue)
    {
        this.dataQueue = dataQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        String temp = null;
        long count = 0;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " running...");

        try
        {
            while(!isDone || !dataQueue.isEmpty())
            {
                temp = dataQueue.take();
                count = temp.length() + count;

                if(count%1000 == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + count);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Final result: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + count);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {

        }
    }

    public void setIsDone(boolean isDone)
    {
        this.isDone = isDone;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions to why this happens?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Here's a crazy suggestion, just because I've been looking at the API just now. Try an AtomicBoolean instead and see what happens? Apparently they are concurrency-ready -- I didnt post this as an answer because I've honestly no idea what the outcome will be. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html

Comment: This happens because `take()` on an empty queue waits until an element is available. See the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/812342/3004881) for ways to accomplish what you're trying to do while still using `take()`.

Answer (score 0):

As Dan Getz already said your worker `take()` waits until an element becomes available but the Queue may be empty.

In your code you check if the Queue is empty but nothing prevents the other Workers to read and remove an element from the element after the check.

If the Queue contains only one element and `t1` and `t2` are two Threads
the following could happen:

```
t2.isEmpty(); // -> false
t1.isEmpty(); // -> false
t2.take(); // now the queue is empty 
t1.take(); // wait forever
```

in this case `t1` would wait "forever".

You can avoid this by using `poll`instead of `take` and check if the result is `null`

```
public void run()
{
    String temp = null;
    long count = 0;
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " running...");

    try
    {
        while(!isDone || !dataQueue.isEmpty())
        {
            temp = dataQueue.poll(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if (temp == null) 
                // re-check if this was really the last element
                continue;

            count = temp.length() + count;

            if(count%1000 == 0)
            {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + count);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Final result: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + count);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        // here it is important to restore the interrupted flag!
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```